Is there an 'easy' way to import SSH keys from GitHub into an Ubuntu install?
One of the features I appreciate on the modern Ubuntu server installer is the ability to import a public SSH key into my initial account during set up. This doesn't work when you're doing a desktop install as far as I know, nor if you're installing a ZFS root system from scratch (since you're running debootstrap).
Is there a way to do similarly — run a script, import a public key to the appropriate place on a installed/running Ubuntu server or desktop instance?

It turns out that Ubuntu has a built in application for this and had it documented. This will import your keys from GitHub:
ssh-import-id gh:username

If you want to import Launchpad keys, you can either leave out the gh: or replace it with lp:.
